# RF remote with three buttons

Tags: rf, remote-control

I am trying to create an RF remote that has 6 buttons but the RF encoder only has 4 inputs.
Is this possible and preferably I would not like to use a separate chip.

This is what I am using:

http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/56726.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IC has four inputs, you can activate multiple inputs at once, for 15 unique switch combinations.

You could use six diodes to decode 6 switches into 4 inputs.

Comment: Of course sorry didnt think of that

Answer (score 0):

It has 4 inputs, which means you can input \$2^4\$ combinations of these inputs. To translate button presses to binary numbers, a priority encoder is needed, such as [this one](http://www.ti.com/product/cd4532b).